# How to create ArrayCollection in MXML

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

```
<s:ArrayCollection id="theCollection">
    <namespace:Items name="name 1" count="5" />
    <namespace:Items name="name 2" count="6" />
    <namespace:Items name="name 3" count="7" />
    <namespace:Items name="name 4" count="8" />
</s:ArrayCollection>
```

here,It's throwing an error unknown namespace can you please illustrate why it is giving error

Answer (score 1):

"namespace" should be your namespace and "Items" the type of object you are making. You can use it like this for example:

```
<s:ArrayCollection id="theCollection">
        <fx:Object name="name 1" count="5" />
        <fx:Object name="name 2" count="6" />
        <fx:Object name="name 3" count="7" />
        <fx:Object name="name 4" count="8" />
    </s:ArrayCollection>
```

This is an arraycollection which contains objects.

Another example would be:

```
<s:ArrayCollection id="theCollection">
        <vo:User name="name 1" count="5" />
        <vo:User name="name 2" count="6" />
        <vo:User name="name 3" count="7" />
        <vo:User name="name 4" count="8" />
    </s:ArrayCollection>
```

In this case, I am making an ArrayCollection containing Users. I use my custom class User which can be found in vo(valueobject package).